# コンテナ内のMariaDBにホストからアクセスする方法は？

Tags: docker, mariadb

[mariadb - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb)

```
$ docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:tag
```

とあるので、`tag`の部分を`latest`に変えて下記のように実行しました（パスワードも下記の通りではなく適当に変えています）。

```
$ docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:latest
```

その後、無事、コンテナ内に入って、データベースを作ったりデータをインサートしたりしたのですが、どのようにしてホストマシーンからコンテナ内のMariaDBにアクセスするのでしょうか？
接続には [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) を使用しています。

[image]

上記項目に

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
User: root
Password: docker run で指定した値
```

としても `Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘127.0.0.1’ (36)` というエラーになります。

Docker Desktop for Macを使用しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLの情報ですが、下記が参考になりました。

[How to Run MySQL in a Docker Container on macOS with Persistent Local Data | by Casey McMullen | Medium](https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-run-mysql-in-a-docker-container-on-macos-with-persistent-local-data-58b89aec496a)

ポートをマッピングさせないといけないようです。ですので、`docker run`時に`-p`でポートを指定します。

```
docker run --name some-mariadb-port -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:latest
```

あとは[TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/)に

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
User: root
Password: docker run で指定した値
```

と指定すれば問題ありません。

蛇足ですが、`docker-compose.yml`を使った場合は下記になります。

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: some-mariadb-port
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
```

もちろん `docker-compose.yml` を使った場合は、`docker run` ではなく、
`docker-compose up -d` を実行してください。